# Trying to close the "join this site" box at the top of a page throws a JavaScript error instead of closing the box

Tags: bug, javascript

I was trying to close this box at the top of https://music.stackexchange.com:

[image: box at top of page]

But every time I hit the X to close, it just throws a JavaScript error instead of closing the box:

[image: JS error]

It's happening in both Firefox 64 and Safari 12, on macOS 10.14. Safari's version of the error:

[image: Safari's version of the error]

Comment: This was already reported on their child meta [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2931) and [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3085).